# Can't use docker on RPi with Raspbian and Pi-Hole installed?

Tags: raspbian, dns, docker, pi-hole

Anyone else running docker AND Pi-Hole on Raspbian?

I wanted to experiment with docker on my RPi, but I've hit a brick wall. After installing the docker.io using apt, it can't seem to pull anything from the repositories. I keep getting either a 'Tag latest not found in repository' error or 'TLS handshake timeout' when specifying a different tag when pulling.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ docker pull hello-world:latest
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
6dd7e8e38242: Pulling fs layer
0e0e51368dbf: Pulling fs layer
Pulling repository docker.io/library/hello-world
Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/library/hello-world

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ docker pull nextcloud:rc-fpm
rc-fpm: Pulling from library/nextcloud
e1cf0272c6e7: Pulling fs layer
ec7769aeef26: Pulling fs layer
d46c3ea3cf53: Pulling fs layer
1e717012bed3: Pulling fs layer
d74110d2b082: Pulling fs layer
f48dc8a9b9cb: Pulling fs layer
3de3a8a262f9: Pulling fs layer
dd109f705e4b: Pulling fs layer
47e7adf112bf: Pulling fs layer
16d4e9901f22: Pulling fs layer
35dc90641aed: Pulling fs layer
97d19624f4bb: Pulling fs layer
88d4ea9e0bbc: Pulling fs layer
1d03df7088da: Pulling fs layer
8479cdcdfe35: Pulling fs layer
77bc14518cd9: Pulling fs layer
b0be80be7dd7: Pulling fs layer
89b743abe262: Pulling fs layer
330d615c1eae: Pulling fs layer
67d26b5e07a0: Pulling fs layer
92dd268cb14f: Pulling fs layer
4fe964875faa: Pulling fs layer
c102a2a36d09: Pulling fs layer
4d57f49c618a: Pulling fs layer
2ba54abdec49: Pulling fs layer
bb815eb77b78: Pulling fs layer
92461d12153e: Pulling fs layer
a94660707236: Pulling fs layer
612d1ee779c8: Pulling fs layer
2d5f90133cc0: Pulling fs layer
59c5927baf08: Pulling fs layer
147e5b4b18cf: Pulling fs layer
e6e7b8c91088: Pulling fs layer
81fb8350f2f4: Pulling fs layer
a2926bd6b76b: Pulling fs layer
Pulling repository docker.io/library/nextcloud
Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories                 /library/nextcloud/images: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

Could this be due to Pi-Hole which is running directly on the host OS? Maybe it's messing with the connection?

No solutions found online have helped me so far..

Comment: What version of the hardware and OS are you running and how did you install docker.io?

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser Hello, late answer but I am still having trouble with docker on my RPi. I am running Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch) on the RPi Model B. First I installed docker from the apt repositories, which resulted in the error documented here, but following that I tried many different versions and methods for installing docker which you can check out in my Reddit post [over here](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/a847b9/docker_impossible_to_get_running_on_raspbian/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem today while pulling resin/rpi-raspbian. Worked in Ubuntu VM, but not on the Pi. I've also used a Pyhton image a week ago. Now I could not pull it anymore. Docker was installed with apt.

(`sudo apt install docker.io`)

I just managed to solve it by removing docker and installing it via a script I found online.

**Remove docker**

```
sudo apt purge docker*
```

**Install docker**

```
curl -fsSL get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh && sh get-docker.sh
```

Source: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-easy-way-to-set-up-docker-on-a-raspberry-pi-7d24ced073ef

Hope this will help!

Comment: Welcome. That script (which you can read via https://get.docker.com/) does not build anything from source.  It identifies your distro and installs it with `apt-get` -- although it may not be doing it quite the same way as you did originally.  You'd have to scrutinize it a bit for the details.

Comment: I must admit that I did not look at the script. Just Googled -
 Docker from source - and this command poped up. However, it solved my problem and it's just another way of installing Docker.

Comment: That script is well recommended. I added my comment in case someone else looking for a solution sees that and thinks, "Yikes! There must be a better way..." -- I don't know how long it would take to build from source on a Pi, but I suspect a while, and source builds are prone to various gotchas.  Put another way, maybe you want to correct that above ;)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have tried running the install script you provided, but that resulted in a SEGV Fault when starting the docker daemon, both stable and testing docker vers. And after some digging I found that the current version of docker might have a bug relating to my current architecture and OS, so I downgraded docker-ce to an earlier version (which got me a dependency error for docker-ce-cli) but now even though it runs all containers are immediately terminated on launch.